# paypal sent money to unregisterd email in paypal via single payout

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I have use paypal php-sdk for transfer money from **My account to customer accounts** wtih [Single Payout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payouts/single-payout/) options. All goes fine, but when the customer email is wrong then shows error

> "RECEIVER_UNREGISTERED: Receiver is unregistered

it's expected. But it sent the payments against wrong email which is not expected. My confusion is..

1. Why it sent payments to unregistered email
2. How can get it back
3. Is there any other way to sent money from my account to customer account

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Why it sent payments to unregistered email

   Answer : Because the email that you set during request was not registered and  it fall to unregistered receiver.
2. How can get it back

   Answer : After 30 days if the status is still unclaimed, PayPal will reverse the amount to the sender.
3. Is there any other way to sent money from my account to customer account

   Answer : You can use send money features from your PayPal account.